# matplotlib Y-axis scale does not match data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here since the y-axis does not look like the data I am using. The data are coming from a Google sheet and seems to go into the dataframe correctly.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(values[1:], columns=values[0])
    df.set_index('date')
    print(df)
    datelist = df.date.tolist()
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'  # check the time format of the timestamp in the first column
    x_axis = [datetime.strptime(dat, fmt) for dat in datelist]
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    plt.plot(x_axis, 'usage', data=df, color='skyblue', linewidth=2, label='Daily Usage')
    plt.plot(x_axis, 'currenttotal', data=df, color='yellow', linewidth=2, label='Total Usage')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Bandwidth Usage')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.savefig('todaysplot.png', dpi=300)
```

Here is the dataframe:

```
`           date      usage    currenttotal
    0    2017-11-08    13          328
    1    2017-11-09    12          340
    2    2017-11-10    12          359
    3    2017-11-11     7          366`
```

If you note in the y-axis ticks I am getting the numbers on the left of the dataframe and want numbers from 0 to 1024 on the left, but have not been able to figure out how to do make this happen.

[image: plot from run]

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't replicate your problem. What is `values` for instance? Or `datetime.strptime`? Imports as well as indentation are part of the script.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a date list.[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

date = ['2017-11-08', '2017-11-09', '2017-11-10', '2017-11-11']
usage = [13, 12, 12, 7]
currenttotal = [328, 340, 359, 366]

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'usage': usage, 'currenttotal': currenttotal})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.plot('date', 'usage', data=df, color='skyblue', linewidth=2, marker='D', label='Daily Usage')
plt.plot('date', 'currenttotal', data=df, color='yellow', linewidth=2, marker='o',label='Total Usage')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Bandwidth Usage')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()

df
Out[13]: 
   currenttotal       date  usage
0           328 2017-11-08     13
1           340 2017-11-09     12
2           359 2017-11-10     12
3           366 2017-11-11      7
```

Or if you want to set the date as the index:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace = True)

plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.plot('usage', data=df, color='skyblue', linewidth=2, marker='D', label='Daily Usage')
plt.plot('currenttotal', data=df, color='yellow', linewidth=2, marker='o',label='Total Usage')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Bandwidth Usage')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()

df
Out[37]: 
            usage  currenttotal
date                           
2017-11-08     13           328
2017-11-09     12           340
2017-11-10     12           359
2017-11-11      7           366
```

Another way to plot after setting date as the index is to use the plot method:

```
plt.figure()
df['usage'].plot(c='blue', linewidth=2, marker='D', label='Daily Usage')
df['currenttotal'].plot(c='red', linewidth=2, marker='o', label='Total Usage')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Bandwidth Usage')
plt.legend(loc='right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

or even more concisely:

```
df.plot(linewidth=2)
plt.ylabel('Bandwidth Usage')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the solution but get the numbers on the side still not range from the values of data i.e something like 0 to 1000 with intermediate ticks.

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, I have explicitly defined the data frame above. Could you copy the first block of code and try it in a new file. You should be able to replicate the graph I have shown here.

Comment: I was able to replicate your results. This helps.  I am looking my at code. Also, validating the dataframe, which looks the same just more data.

Comment: KRKirov, thanks for the examples!  I determined the data coming from the Google Sheet API was formatting the numbers as strings.  I was able to use the valueRenderOption to put out unformatted numbers and now just have to convert the dates from strings to datetime format.

Comment: OK, it looks like you going to solve your problem. You can also convert strings to a numeric type using pd.to_numeric https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html . If you have a problem with the density of ticks on your y axis then you can use plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1000, 100)) before plt.show() and adjust the maximum and the step as appropriate.